# Excel VBA validation with more than 1 row

Tags: excel, validation, if-statement

How do I write the code that would auto scan the last row and see if the value has been input?
eg. sometimes I have 1 row, sometimes I have 3 rows, 5 rows etc of data in the excel to do the data validation.
Below is my code but only do 1 row.

```
Private Sub Validation()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Data")

Data_1 = ws.Cells(2, 10).Value
Data_2 = ws.Cells(2, 17).Value
Data_3 = ws.Cells(2, 18).Value

If Data_1 = "" Then
MsgBox "Data_1 is not entered", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If

If Data_2 = "" Then
MsgBox "G_dormant_company is not entered", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. the VBA needs to know if there are 1, 3, or 5 rows. Once VBA knows that, it can do a validation in the last row.

Comment: Hi, its sometimes 1 row, sometimes 3, sometimes 4 rows...etc....if cant fix that, is it ok to set it as 10 rows?

Comment: You need to improve your question and show your sample data. It is not possible to answer it like it is.